# Find the page load time of external URLs

Tags: google-analytics-api, pageload, pagespeed, page-load-time, navigation-timing-api

Is there a way to find the page load time for external URLs?
My task is to compile a table of page load times for a list of URLs. I have read about the navigation timing API but could not find a way to find the page load time for an external URL that I specify in code. For example, something like http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ which analyzes the page load time for the URL we enter(I'm not sure if this is accurate)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.webpagetest.org/ is a great tool for this.

It measures the Page Load Time, Speed Index (probably a better measure of speed) and can even show you videos and waterfall diagrams!