# Benchmark angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs, protractor, benchmarking

I'm tring to benchmark my AngularJS app. My goal is to mesure some load times to avoid regressions.

To do this, I tried phantomas, with the add of new metrics (for exemple with an event at the begin and end of the d3 graph render or a table render wih angular). The problem is the use of Phantom.js, whom does't render well Angular js apps. A simple screenshot with Phantom js shows us the poor rendering quality. The ultimate use of phantomas would be grunt-phantomas, that monitor these metrics in beautiful graphics.

Have you got an idea to achieve this benchmark. I thought about protractor but it hasn't been designed to benchmark any load time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find the page load time of external URLs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23427506/find-the-page-load-time-of-external-urls)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PerfJankie:Error: The environment you requested is not available](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378830/perfjankieerror-the-environment-you-requested-is-not-available)